# what is the use of the function DosPathToSessionPath?

Tags: function, kernel

I am doing a small analysis in file functions in kernel dll. I noticed this function called 
DosPathToSessionPath. I googled for it. There is no much documentation about this. Can anybody tell me what is the use of this function?

Answer (score 0):

The `DosPathToSessionPath` is not documented. Here is a small C# code which use `DosPathToSessionPath`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DosPathToSessionPath {
    static class NativeMethods {
        [DllImport ("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool DosPathToSessionPath (
            uint sessionId, String pInPath, out IntPtr ppOutPath);

        [DllImport ("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId ();

        [DllImport ("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr LocalFree (IntPtr hMem);
    }
    class Program {
        static void Main (string[] args) {
            uint sessionId = NativeMethods.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId ();
            string filePath = @"C:\Program Files";
            IntPtr ppOutPath;
            bool statusCode = NativeMethods.DosPathToSessionPath (
                                    sessionId, filePath, out ppOutPath);
            if (statusCode) {
                string outPath = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto (ppOutPath);
                Console.WriteLine (outPath);
                ppOutPath = NativeMethods.LocalFree (ppOutPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not clear in which situations the function should be used. Is the session path is a path like `\Sessions\1\DosDevices\C:\Program Files` or like `C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files`?

This code an you see as a starting point of some experiments. Currently the output path of `DosPathToSessionPath` (`ppOutPath`) is always the same as the input path.

Comment: it was actually along time before,actually when I went throu' research of this function..Its been noticed that this function only identifies the type of path..wether its defined frm kernel space(ex:\Sessions\1\DosDevices\Drive\Program Files) or frm user mode.